# Number of Pages in PDF - Mac

Tags: macos, pdf

I have a folder with pdf files. I want print of name of files along with number of pages the pdf file is having. I am using macbook.

I can easily get the print of name of files by dropping the specific folder to printer icon, but getting number of pages along with it is very difficult.

As I've researched , spotlight has an option of number of pages while searching and the same has been referred by many people in forums which require use of applescript or terminal commands.

Is there a simple way to get number of pages along with name of pdf file or else can we manipulate the spotlight index thing to view number of pages as an option in "list view".

Comment: Are you opposed to using shell commands or applescript? Either could be used to solve your request.

Comment: The advice of "many people in forums" is a good one. It is indeed the simplest way to get at that information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A shell solution using tools supplied in OS X:

```
mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemNumberOfPages  ./*.pdf | cut -d= -f 2 | paste - -
```

Comment: That's an excellent solution - have my vote. By the way, you don't need `./*.pdf` as `*.pdf` is sufficient.

Comment: The total number:  mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemNumberOfPages  *.pdf |grep NumberOfPages | cut -d" " -f3 | paste -s -d+ - | bc

Answer (score 1):

Thanks people for the help, I tried all the above solutions. Pdfinfo and pdftk required initial installations like xpdf, xquartz etc. Both pdfinfo and pdftk gave warning & error messages, though both of them gave output but missed name of some pdf files. Another thing is pdftk didn't scanned sub-folders.

Of all, msdl command, worked perfectly, gave all filenames with number of pages. It included files in sub-folders too.

Now, here's another solution which I've copied from [here](http://robservatory.com/total-pdf-pages-in-documents-by-folder/). Its very neat and perfect. There's more on this webpage w.r.t subfolders. Here is the shell script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

myFiles=($(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pdf"))
myFileCount=${#myFiles[*]}
totalPages=0
i=0

while [ $i -lt $myFileCount ]
do
    prettyName=$(echo ${myFiles[i]}|cut -c 3-999)
    pageCount=$(mdls ${myFiles[i]} | grep kMDItemNumberOfPages | awk -F'= ' '{print $2}')
    size=${#pageCount}
    if [ $size -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo $prettyName : \*\* Skipped - no page count \*\*
  else
    # Pad the results for nice alignment of page counts
    digitCount=${#pageCount}
    case $digitCount in
        1)
            padding="    ";;
        2)
            padding="   ";;
        3)
            padding="  ";;
        4)
            padding=" ";;
        *) ;;
    esac
    echo "$padding$pageCount: $prettyName"

    totalPages=$(($totalPages + $pageCount))  
  fi

  i=$(( $i + 1 ))

done

# Pad the results for nice alignment of grand total
digitCount=${#totalPages}
case $digitCount in
    1)
        padding="    ";;
    2)
        padding="   ";;
    3)
        padding="  ";;
    4)
        padding=" ";;
    *) ;;
esac

echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "$padding$totalPages: Total PDF pages in this folder"

IFS=$saveIFS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a little shell script then you might try this:

First, install and install the pdf tools from here: http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html This will give you the very handy pdfinfo.

You can then get info about a PDF file by opening Terminal and typing:

```
pdfinfo "/path/to/your/file.pdf"
```

...or to write the results to a file on your desktop:

```
pdfinfo "/path/to/your/file.pdf" | egrep "^(Pages:|Title:)" > ~/Desktop/info.txt
```

...or to scan a folder, as per your original question:

```
find "/path/to/your/folder" -name "*.pdf" | while read thePDFFile; do pdfinfo "$thePDFFile" | egrep "^(Pages:|Title:)" >> ~/Desktop/info.txt ; echo --- >> ~/Desktop/info.txt; done
```

...obviously replacing "/path/to/your/folder" with the path to your folder.

Hope that's of some help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another shell script solution, uses `pdftk` instead of `pdfinfo`, uses a `for` loop instead of a `find|while` (so only find PDFs in the current folder) and produces a tab-separated output of names and page counts:

```
for f in *.pdf ; do echo -e -n $f '\t' ; (pdftk $f dump_data|grep ^NumberOfPages) ; done
```

typical output:

```
0033-0124%2E00250.pdf   NumberOfPages: 19
hooky.pdf   NumberOfPages: 1
hunt100.pdf     NumberOfPages: 1
huntmap.pdf     NumberOfPages: 1
hunt.pdf    NumberOfPages: 1
map1.pdf    NumberOfPages: 1
msoas.pdf   NumberOfPages: 1
RelativeRisk.pdf    NumberOfPages: 16
```